# search string containing line break/newline/linefeed in a file in Unix

Tags: awk

I am searching a string (string includes new line/line break) in a file and printing 2 lines after pattern match e.g.
file contains:- (edited)

```
           <cfu>
              <statm1>
              <status>good</status>
           </cfu>
           <cfu>
              <statm2>
              <status>not found</status>
           </cfu>
           <cfu>
              <statm3>
              <status>empty</status>
           </cfu>
           <cfa>
              <statm1>
              <status>good</status>
           </cfa>
           <cfa>
              <statm2>
              <status>not found</status>
           </cfa>
           <cfa>
              <statm3>
              <status>empty</status>
           </cfa>
```

i tried like

```
awk -v RS=""'/<cfu> <statm1/{i=NR+2}(NR<=i){print}' file_name
```

but no luck, please help

expected output:-

```
           <cfu>
              <statm1>
              <status>good</status>
           </cfu>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pleaseputsomewhitespaceinyourcodeespeciallywhenaskingotherstoreadittotrytohelpyou. Or to put it another way -  Please put some white space in your code, especially when asking others to read it to try to help you.

Comment: Is that meant to be XML? Shouldn't there be a `</statmx>` for each `<statmx>` or should they be `<statmx/>` instead?

Comment: Yes, this XML is invalid, that's why I can't use `xmmllint` in my answer, and I need to reformat with xmlstarlet or use xidel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying to decode the XML (the input doesn't look fully like XML anyway), using `pcregrep`'s `M`ultiline mode:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo '(?s)<cfu>(?:(?!</cfu>).)*<statm1>.*?</cfu>' your-file
<cfu>
              <statm1>
              <status>good</status>
           </cfu>
```

- `(?s)` turns on the `s` flag which causes `.` to also match on newline characters.
- `(?!</cfu>).` is any character (`.`) that is not the start of `</cfu>`. We match 0 or more of that with `*`. We use that in place of `.*` to make sure we don't run past the next closing `</cfu>`.
- `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`.

If you only wanted the `<status>` value:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)<cfu>(?=(?2)*<status>([^<]*))((?!</cfu>).)*<statm1>.*?</cfu>' your-file
good
```

Answer (score 1):

### With a proper HTML/XML parser, after surrounding your file with `root` node:

##### With `xidel`:

```
xidel --output-node-format=xml -e '//cfu[contains(., "good")]' file
```

Output:

```
<cfu>
          <statm1>
          <status>good
       </status></statm1></cfu>
```

##### With `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet format -H file | sponge file
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//cfu[contains(., "good")]' file 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
<cfu>
          <statm1>
          <status>good
       </status></statm1></cfu>
```